# SQL Server - Insert data into temporary table from another server

Tags: sql-server

The problem we are fancing is we have to make some inserts/updates into a certain database of one server based on the data from another server. The first idea that came to my mind was using **linked servers**, but it was rejected by the database management team (unfortunately, we were given no reasons for such a prohibition). I suggested to split the task into two SQL scripts, so we force the first one to print out the data we want to use from the first server, so it could be pasted into de second script por update the second server (it was also rejected).

For short: we have some data in a server *A* table *T*, and we want to query *T* in order to extract some data and insert it into a *temporary table* of server B **without using linked servers**. Once the data is inserted into the *temporary table* then we could write a T-SQL script for use this data to update some tables from server *B*. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would write a PowerShell script or custom app code.

Comment: Is this a one-off or a regular process?

Comment: You could use  OPENROWSET. Maybe this will help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373221/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-get-data-from-another-sql-server-without-setting-l

Comment: Bit of a silly restriction. I suppose `OPENROWSET` isn't *technically* the same as linked servers, but personally I would go for linked servers. Barring that, Powershell or a LinqPad script would do the job

Answer (score 0):

The solution that comes to my mind is, you can make a procedure to save the data in the csv file after each insert. Then, the second server can check the csv file with some conditions like (if it's not empty), insert it into the table in the second server, then run another query to make a csv file empty after inserting it to the second server. Then you can update the second server based on your requirements. I hope this solution helps you.